Up to date documentation for Javascript for Automation (JXA)
Is there an up-to-date official documentation about Javascript for Automation (JXA)?
I can find this, from 2015, Introduction to JavaScript for Automation Release Notes.
Is there anything newer?

See also Is JXA still supported?

Don't wait for anything new official as Apple is not actively maintaining and for sure not improving this functionality.
But if you want a more comprehensive Documentation I can recommend on

JXA-Cookbook a community maintained wiki
bru6.de/jxa an extensive guide to JXA by Christian Kirsch (maintained at least up to the end of 2023)

EDIT:

JXA Resources a 2021 updated resource list that helped me to find a lot of relevant resources


It's strange, because the fact that you can script OS with javascript is great. But the actual implementation is... yeah. Bugs and weird behaviour all around
